# Still Not Working.. Swapping .innerHTML with .js variable

Tags: javascript, html

**When the user visits the page, this HTML text must display.**

```
<p id="exampleText">Hit The "Change Text" Button Below To Change <span id="thisText"><strong>This</strong></span> Text and see how the innerHTML property tag works </p>
```

**After clicking this button:**

```
<button id="changeButton" type="button" value="default Text" onclick="textChanger()">Change Text</button>
```

**Display This Text:**

```
var txtExmp1 = "Hooooooooooooraayy!!, You Clicked and Changed The Text..." + "<br><br><br>" + "but now you have to fix me so i can change again";
```

Now user should be able to click the button and see previous text and back to the "Hooray" message in `var txtExmp1`.

I've tried to use an if statement but didnt work. Here's the code:

```
var defaultText = document.getElementById("exampleText");

      if (defaultTex.innerHTML === defaultText){
          defaultText.innerHTML = txtExmp1;
      }  
      else {
          defaultText.innerHTML = defaultText;
      }
```

How can I make this texts toggle between each other considering one is html and the other is javascript. What is the simple and most effective way to toggle this texts?

Heres what it looks like (Screenshot image):
 [i.Before Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzdvD.png)
[ii.After click, but wont change again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8QA7.png)

Comment: Could you please put the code up on something like https://jsfiddle.net ? Or put your code here in a CSS/HTML/JavaScript block

Comment: This code won't even compile - defaultTex spelling mistake in the first if statement. Please use Developer Tools in Chrome to debug JavaScript - it will help you massively.

Comment: Your first if condition says defaultTex.innerHTML, missing the t at the end of defaultText

Comment: `defaultText.innerHTML = defaultText` you're assigning a DOM element to innerHTML ...

Comment: @ChrisDixon JavaScript does not compile :P

Comment: and if the `defaultTex.` should be `defaultText.` .. .then the code as is, the if condition will ALWAYS be false ... since a DOM element is never equal to its innerHTML

Comment: so, clearly the code you've posted is not really the code you actually have, because either nothing will change, or the innerHTML would be something like `[object Object]`

Comment: @Elias Here is the entire code : https://jsfiddle.net/z59803bf/#&togetherjs=qKPMvKUhzt

Comment: @Elias true! I should choose my words more carefully! ;)

Comment: Now when i run it i get:  [object HTMLParagraphElement]

Comment: Like I said.. please give me a working example on https://jsfiddle.net so I can get a look at the debugging log

Comment: @JaromandaX what will be the best way to go about it? https://jsfiddle.net/boringprogrammer/z59803bf/1/#&togetherjs=qKPMvKUhzt

Comment: @Elias I pasted the whole code here: https://jsfiddle.net/boringprogrammer/z59803bf/1/#&togetherjs=qKPMvKUhzt

Comment: I don't know - please show the code that produces the output you claim to have gotten, since the code in that fiddle will just throw an error without changing anything

Comment: here's a paired down version https://jsfiddle.net/m5zrfqv9/ ... without all that other crap popping up everywhere ... see the error when you click? even your fiddle produces the same error `ReferenceError: defaultTex is not defined` - so your images claiming your code changes the innerHTML are false

Comment: @JaromandaX defaultTex was an error, it's actually 'defaultText'.  even though i have corrected it i get an error. and for my images, the code i used to achieve that results was document.getElementById("exampleText").innerHTML = txtExmp1;

Comment: You still haven't posted code that could possibly produce the images you posted - please show that code, not this code that clearly wont work either - because fixing that typo, clicking on the button, results in the innerHTML changing to `[object HTMLParagraphElement]` not "hooray" etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word you are searching is toggle. Try switch case:

```
var theToggle = document.getElementById("changeButton");
var toggleMe = document.getElementById("exampleText"); 
toggleMe.toggleStatus = "on";

theToggle.onclick = function(){
  switch(toggleMe.toggleStatus){
    case "on":
      toggleMe.toggleStatus="off";
      toggleMe.textContent = "Hooooooooooooraayy";
      break;
    case "off":
      toggleMe.toggleStatus="on";
      toggleMe.textContent = " Hit The Change Text Button Below To change...";
      break;
  }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Can you explain to me how you got 'toggleMe.toggleStatus ?', How did toggleStatus know on and off as bool?

Comment: It is an index in order to decide what case will be next (when the user click on the button again). You can change it to what you want, and of course you can use more then 2 options.

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively simple, when changing the text you need to take the current visible one and save it in a variable, then show the other stored text you have in `txtExmp1` then when the use click again you take the other visible text store it and show the one you stored before, doing it this is highly inefficient.

From the start you store both strings in variables or array then toggle between them.

Of course this is just one way to achieve this.

```js
let text = ["Hooooooooooooraayy!!, You Clicked and Changed The Text... <br><br><br>but now you have to fix me so i can change again", "Hit The Change Text Button Below To Change <span id='thisText '><strong>This</strong></span> Text and see how the innerHTML property tag works "];
let index = 0;

function textChanger() {
  // Get the p Element refrence so we can modify it
  var pElement = document.getElementById("exampleText");
  // text[index] will return one of the texts from the array
  // depening on the index if 0 its the first one
  // if 1 it's the second one
  // that's why we're altering index's value after every change
  
  if (index == 0) {
    pElement.innerHTML = text[index];
    index = 1;
  } else if (index == 1) {
    pElement.innerHTML = text[index];
    index = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="exampleText">Hit The Change Text Button Below To Change <span id='thisText '><strong>This</strong></span> Text and see how the innerHTML property tag works </p>

<button id="changeButton" type="button" value="default Text" onclick="textChanger()">Change Text</button>
```

Comment: When used this method, the function works except that the text text in var txtExmp1 does not show.

Comment: You mustn't copy the code as it is, in my example there's no `var txtExmp1`, you need take that code and adjust it to fit your needs